# How can I add any kind of noise to image for a given SNR?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, noise

What is the best way to add any kind of noise (not only Gaussian noise) to 2D signal (image) for a given SNR?

Comment: Hi! Asking for code written to a specification is explicitly off-topic here, so I removed that from your question. So, what's the question here? You generate noise and you add it to your image data. Where specifically can we help you?

Comment: Hi. To a clear image, I want to add noise (generally any kind of noise, not only awgn). As a result, I want to obtain a noisy image with given SNR (for example 5dB).

Comment: yes. you asked that. What is the precise thing you need help with? Like, as said, you generate noise, and you add that. What exactly in these steps do you not understand? If you ask precisely, we can help you!

Comment: I do not understand how to generate a noise resulting in a noisy image with given SNR.

Comment: OK, so where's the problem in generating the noise with the given SNR, specifically? Can you try to narrow that down?

Comment: For example, I want to add to a clear image Rayleigh noise. How to generate this noise with a given SNR?

Comment: so, do you know how to generate Rayleigh-distributed noise in general? is the problem that you don't understand what "SNR" means? Or is the problem that you don't know what power is? This is really tiring... it feels like you're really not trying to find the first step you need help with, but always try to make us do your whole work instead of helping you with the one thing that you actually need help with. You probably could have had an answer by now if you could just sit down and write a precise question.

Comment: SNR is the signal power divided by the noise power. Sounds like you have the signal (the noise free image) already, so you need to (1) calculate the signal power and from that you can (2) calculate the noise power for a given SNR. Do you need help with (1), (2), or both (1) and (2)?